# create an ArrayList, with a hashmap in each value

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am looking to create an arraylist, with a hashmap in each value. Not sure how to even start this? Anybody have some old code, or can help out?

Comment: what language are you looking for? java?

Answer (score 1):

In Java

```
ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>> list = new Arraylist<>();
list.add(new HashMap<Integer, String>());
list.get(0).put(1, "Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

With generic in Java:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,String>> david = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,String>>();
david.add(new HashMap<Integer,String>());
```